# Results of Azure SQL Vulnerability Assesment

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-resource-manager, azure-sql-server, azure-security

I want to configure Security Baselines for Azure SQL Database via ARM Template.

[I am referring to the sample code:](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/sql-vulnerability-assessment#using-resource-manager-templates)

```
"resources": [
      {
         "type": "Microsoft.Sql/servers/databases/vulnerabilityAssessments/rules/baselines",
         "apiVersion": "2018-06-01-preview",
         "name": "[concat(parameters('server_name'),'/', parameters('database_name') , '/default/VA2065/master')]",
         "properties": {
            "baselineResults": [
               {
                  "result": [
                     "FirewallRuleName3",
                     "StartIpAddress",
                     "EndIpAddress"
                  ]
               },
               {
                  "result": [
                     "FirewallRuleName4",
                     "62.92.15.68",
                     "62.92.15.68"
                  ]
               }
            ]
         },
         "type": "Microsoft.Sql/servers/databases/vulnerabilityAssessments/rules/baselines",
         "apiVersion": "2018-06-01-preview",
         "name": "[concat(parameters('server_name'),'/', parameters('database_name'), '/default/VA2130/Default')]",
         "dependsOn": [
            "[resourceId('Microsoft.Sql/servers/vulnerabilityAssessments', parameters('server_name'), 'Default')]"
         ],
         "properties": {
            "baselineResults": [
               {
                  "result": [
                     "dbo"
                  ]
               }
            ]
         }
      }
   ]
```

My question is, How do I get the RESULT of 'VA1248,VA2108,VA2109' from Azure portal, so I can use it in my ARM template?

Investigating further - In the reference code, the RESULT for 'VA2130' is 'dbo', but in the portal, it returns something else. So, how do I calculate the RESULTS for my baselines, so I can use them in the ARM template?

[image]